# Using Devise, how can I run Javascript code when a user signs up or logs in via login or cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, analytics, user-management, kissmetrics

[KISSmetrics](http://kissmetrics.com) says that you should [identify the user](http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/common-methods), via a line of Javascript, in two scenarios:

1. When a user successfully signs up
2. When a user successfully logs in, either through cookies or through a login page

I am using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user management. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think the easiest mechanism would be to expose a token from the sign up and log in actions, something as simple as boolean, e.g., `@signed_up = true` or whatever.

Once they've signed up or logged in, they'll be taken to a page. That page's `.rhtml` (or haml, or...) would check for the presence of that token. If it's there, some JavaScript would be rendered, or a file included, etc. that would perform the required KISSmetrics JavaScript code you need.